# Copy database to another server in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, wiredtiger

I am using Robomongo in my local machine. Robomongo is using wired tiger storage engine to store my dbs.
Now when I want to copy my database to a remote machine I am using :

```
db.copyDatabase("localDBName","remoteDBName","localMachineAddress")
```

The wired tiger storage engine is creating an unknown .wt format because of which the above command is not able to copy the database.

On copying empty database is getting created at the remote machine.

Comment: Are you copying database from local machine?

Comment: Copying from localmachine to remotemachine

Comment: if that is case, you'll need to connect with remote database in shell and execute this command from there. see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/

Comment: I am doing all the connections. I made a dummy db on the remote machine and copied it to local machine. That is working fine. I am getting that db in local machine.

Comment: It's the other way it's not working because wiredtiger is creating some .wt extension files which is not allowing the db to get copied.